# using Native AndroidMessageHandler throws System.ObjectDisposedException: Cannot access a closed Stream. on MAUI

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, maui

I am doing an http request so if I used the default self signed credentials i had issues and couldn't make the request so I override it

I am doing a post request within my local network so I have used the following code to override the behaviour to check the credentials

```
#if DEBUG
        var httpHelper = new HttpClientHandlerHelper();
 builder.Services.AddSingleton<HttpClient>(x=> new HttpClient(httpHelper.GetInsecureHandler(), false));

#else
        builder.Services.AddSingleton<HttpClient>();
#endif
```

where it is defined as

```
 public CustomAndroidMessageHandler GetInsecureHandler()
 {
        var handler = new CustomAndroidMessageHandler();
        handler.ClientCertificateOptions = ClientCertificateOption.Manual;
        handler.ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = (message, cert, chain, errors) =>
        {
            // if (cert.Issuer.Equals("CN=localhost"))
            return true;
        };
        return handler;
    }
```

and the Android handler

```
 public class CustomAndroidMessageHandler : AndroidMessageHandler
    {
        protected override IHostnameVerifier GetSSLHostnameVerifier(HttpsURLConnection connection)
            => new CustomHostnameVerifier();

        private sealed class CustomHostnameVerifier : Java.Lang.Object, IHostnameVerifier
        {
            public bool Verify(string hostname, ISSLSession session)
                => HttpsURLConnection.DefaultHostnameVerifier.Verify(hostname, session)
                    || (hostname == "192.168.250.3" && session.PeerPrincipal.Name == "CN=localhost");
        }
    }
```

at the moment of calling `httpClient.PostAsync()` with the Native handler it throws

```
System.ObjectDisposedException: Cannot access a closed Stream.
   at System.IO.MemoryStream.EnsureNotClosed()
   at System.IO.MemoryStream.get_Length()
   at System.Net.Http.HttpContent.GetComputedOrBufferLength()
   at System.Net.Http.Headers.HttpContentHeaders.get_ContentLength()
   at Xamarin.Android.Net.AndroidMessageHandler.SetupRequestBody(HttpURLConnection httpConnection, HttpRequestMessage request) in /Users/runner/work/1/s/xamarin-android/src/Mono.Android/Xamarin.Android.Net/AndroidMessageHandler.cs:line 1132
   at Xamarin.Android.Net.AndroidMessageHandler.SetupRequestInternal(HttpRequestMessage request, URLConnection conn) in /Users/runner/work/1/s/xamarin-android/src/Mono.Android/Xamarin.Android.Net/AndroidMessageHandler.cs:line 984
   at Xamarin.Android.Net.AndroidMessageHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in /Users/runner/work/1/s/xamarin-android/src/Mono.Android/Xamarin.Android.Net/AndroidMessageHandler.cs:line 374
   at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.<SendAsync>g__Core|83_0(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpCompletionOption completionOption, CancellationTokenSource cts, Boolean disposeCts, CancellationTokenSource pendingRequestsCts, CancellationToken originalCancellationToken)
   at MauiAppTest.Common.Services.ChatServicesService.CreateUser(String phoneNumber) in C:\Users\PontiacGTX\Source\Repos\MauiAppTest\Common\Services\MainService.cs:line 38}
```

using the HttpClientHandler

```
also using HttpClientHandler gives this exception System.ObjectDisposedException: Cannot access a closed Stream.
   at System.IO.MemoryStream.EnsureNotClosed()
   at System.IO.MemoryStream.get_Length()
   at System.Net.Http.HttpContent.GetComputedOrBufferLength()
   at System.Net.Http.Headers.HttpContentHeaders.get_ContentLength()
   at Xamarin.Android.Net.AndroidMessageHandler.SetupRequestBody(HttpURLConnection httpConnection, HttpRequestMessage request) in /Users/runner/work/1/s/xamarin-android/src/Mono.Android/Xamarin.Android.Net/AndroidMessageHandler.cs:line 1132
   at Xamarin.Android.Net.AndroidMessageHandler.SetupRequestInternal(HttpRequestMessage request, URLConnection conn) in /Users/runner/work/1/s/xamarin-android/src/Mono.Android/Xamarin.Android.Net/AndroidMessageHandler.cs:line 984
   at Xamarin.Android.Net.AndroidMessageHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in /Users/runner/work/1/s/xamarin-android/src/Mono.Android/Xamarin.Android.Net/AndroidMessageHandler.cs:line 374
   at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.<SendAsync>g__Core|83_0(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpCompletionOption completionOption, CancellationTokenSource cts, Boolean disposeCts, CancellationTokenSource pendingRequestsCts, CancellationToken originalCancellationToken)
   at AppTest.Common.Services.ChatServicesService.CreateUser(String phoneNumber) in C:\Users\PontiacGTX\Source\Repos\MauiAppTest\Common\Services\MainService.cs:line 38
```

Comment: Could you try to debug and find what the closed Stream is?

Comment: @LiyunZhang-MSFT i have pasted the exception for each case, i dont see much more in the exception but I am sure that the close stream is when reading to end the response message  https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/407a5bd1a6075c182be282a67e0153cc64a03142/src/libraries/System.Net.Http/src/System/Net/Http/HttpClient.cs#L514 This maybe disposes the stream somewhere..here? https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/4ff5a3a85a9b0de7ab9e9267959e668142815f4f/src/libraries/System.Net.Http/src/System/Net/Http/HttpMessageInvoker.cs#L124

Comment: @LiyunZhang-MSFT I think the issue is related that I am using an old version of this file? because apparently there is a newer version but I am not sure why it is not reading the stream when getting the response message https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-android/blob/6290a9c63251e7bbbb3a40ab5bdd230688267b85/src/Mono.Android/Xamarin.Android.Net/AndroidClientHandler.Legacy.cs#L363

Comment: Where did you create the httpclient? According to [this](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/1260), it should be `#if __ANDROID__
  return new HttpClient(new Xamarin.Android.Net.AndroidMessageHandler());
#else
  return new HttpClient();
#endif`.

Comment: @LiyunZhang-MSFT thank you I will try it but they found out it was a bug